# No need to useEffect in this introductory sample code?

Tags: reactjs

From the React documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks
), I found this sample code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It seems that there is no need to use `useEffect` if I create a new onClick function that does both `setCount` and assignment to `document.title`.  Or is there any benefit to use `useEffect` here?

Comment: There are other ways to do the same thing, but it's just an example. The behaviour is fully explained under the example in the docs.

Comment: I real life, you must pass count as a second param of the useEffect hook.

Comment: I agree that this is just an example.  But this is probably not the best example if it's not substantially natural to implement this feature with `useEffect`.  The more I think about this, `useEffect` may be used when the the event is not user-driven (like mount/unmount event when Components are used.)  In this case, a button click can invoke a handler that does everything.

Comment: Here's a version that does not use `useEffect`. https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-wind-z39zt

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use useEffect for this example, you would have to add the count as a dependency to the useEffect. That way the component will update every time the count changes.  It would be added to the useEffect as a second parameter within an array of dependencies.  If no parameters are used it would just act like component did mount.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Another way could just be to use a class component as well.

Comment: question was not that, Button onclick we can set the what ever the useEffect things we can do simple, he asking what is the use of useEffect?.